# 70s (or earlier) pulp Sci Fi book with a Conan-type character and enemies shaped like asparagus

Tags: story-identification, books, pulp

Book was a pulp sci-fi paperback which would have been purchased from a newsstand circa mid 70s.

Cover had hero (a Conan-type with a tight, dark haircut) on a horse with 6 legs (I think).  Pic was very pseudo-[Frazetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Frazetta).

Environment might have been snow-covered but I'm not sure.  Hero was wielding a thin scimitar but I think he was holding it close to his body.  Horse may have been rearing up.
Possibly a hot young woman with furs that didn't cover her very much.

Hero may have been called "Black" but I'm not sure.

Can't remember much of the story except for there was sex and mention of antagonists that were shaped like Asparagus (not kidding).

Book was part of a series about this hero and these asparagus beings were in other stories according to a reference.

Answer (score 10):

The 6-legged horses make me think of John Carter of Mars.  After a little bit of digging, I found something similar to what you describe.  Your entire description sounds like the world of Barsoom.  As far as asparagus, there are creatures that are tall, skinny, green, and have 4 arms.  I don't recall them being compared to asparagus, but now that you point it out, I can see that comparison.

I was only able to find this cover on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1772261580), but it sounds like what you describe.

[image]

John Carter of Mars is the protagonist of a [series of books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Rice_Burroughs#Barsoom_series) by [Edgar Rice Burroughs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_Rice_Burroughs), starting with *A Princess of Mars*.  The artwork is similar to [Boris Vallejo's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Vallejo) work, and he might have even been the artist.  There are similarities to the original Tarzan novels, and they are both by the same author.

Comment: They should make this into a movie.

Comment: They should make this into a good movie.